# Shipment Label Change

Tags: magento2, template, shipment

I want to know that form which file this label is coming:

[image: label on page]

Comment: Write more and post full screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section comes from the `Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi` module, specially it is defined in:

- For new: `magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_new.xml`
- For view: `magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml`

Template is: `magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui/view/adminhtml/templates/shipment/inventory.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\InventoryShippingAdminUi\Block\Adminhtml\Shipment\Inventory $block */

$sourceCode = $block->getSourceCode();
?>

<?php if ($sourceCode): ?>
<section class="admin__page-section inventory">
    <div class="admin__page-section-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Inventory')) ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__page-section-content">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Source:')) ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSourceName($sourceCode)) ?>
    </div>
</section>
<input name="sourceCode" type="hidden" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $sourceCode ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```